# user input to dataframe for selected data

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

how to get selected data from Pandas Dataframe by user input
I am using Tkinter.

```
mfa2 = Entry(page1, width = 100).grid(row=0, column=6)   # get the city like as Karachi

df = pd.read_csv('d://new.csv')   # this is my Dataframe

filter = df["city"] == mfa2
df. Where(filter,inplace=True)
```

but dear, this code did not give me the result, which gave a null value

please guide me how to give the user input to dataframe for the selected data

Thank you in advance

Comment: In python, `x = y().z()` will set `x` to the result of `z()`. In tkinter, `grid()` will always return `None`, thus `mfa2` will be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is rather easy. Just to make my work easy and since I don't know the whole code I am adding a tkinter button just to run the function, here's the code:

```
def filter_data():
    user_input = mfa2.get()
    filtered_df = df[df["city"] == user_input]
    print(filtered_df)

mfa2 = tk.Entry(page1, width=100)
mfa2.grid(row=0, column=6)

df = pd.read_csv('d://new.csv')

filter_button = tk.Button(page1, text="Filter", command=filter_data).grid(row=1, column=6)
```

Lemme know if this code is working for you, cause its working for me just fine.
I created an example data for a .csv file this is my csv data:

```
city,population,country
Karachi,14910000,Pakistan
Lahore,12188000,Pakistan
Islamabad,1014825,Pakistan
Karachi,15210000,Pakistan
Islamabad,1065000,Pakistan
```

and then tried out the code to extract the data in a filtered format here's the result I got:

```
      city  population   country
0  Karachi    14910000  Pakistan
3  Karachi    15210000  Pakistan
```

Comment: This code won't work. It makes the same mistake as the OP: `mfa2` will be `None`, so the call to `mfa2.get()` will fail.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong are you using the function without an input in the entry. It will give you null only if you have no text to search in the entry or maybe because of the case that ex: you are searching Karachi from the database but the user is typing karachi instead of Karachi

Comment: Read my comment again. Calling `get()` won't return `None` (ever!). The problem is that `mfa2` is `None`, thus it is impossible to call `get()` on that object.

Comment: So technically the code I provided is working like a charm, if I had the rest of the code I would have resolved that issue. Sorry for that

Comment: No, the code you provided is _not_ working at all. It will throw an error when `filter_data` is called. It will throw an error because `mfa2` is `None`, and `None.get()` causes an error.

Comment: Then I can only work with the complete code can I get the snippet of the functions connecting to the code snippet you sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256423/discussion-between-ashhaddevlab-and-bryan-oakley).

Comment: No, you don't need the complete code. All you need to do is separate `mfa2 = tk.Entry(page1, width=100).grid(row=0, column=6)` into two lines: `mfa2 = tk.Entry(page1, width=100)` and ` mfa2`.grid(row=0, column=6)`, and then explain why that is necessary.

Comment: Sorry for that @BryanOakley its just that your question doesn't contain the right details to point out the error, so the error you were facing is that when we call a variable and assign a tkinter widget to it and then immediately use the `.grid()` function or any other widget variable in the same line it causes the widget variable to be `None` hence your error. So you simply have to put `.grid()` in another line. Sorry again.

Comment: I'm not the one that posted the question. I'm pointing out that you made the same mistake as the OP in the code you posted. The code you posted will not work because of this mistake.

Comment: thank you for your reply It work within two line ---- New sir, how do I give the two date selection form date and end date? Also, how do you give the integer or number? for df data selection: thank you in advance for your valuable reply

Comment: @badarQureshi Sorry to say but I cant understand what you are trying to say maybe a snippet would make it easier for me to understand ``

Comment: dear how to use this user input as dataframe column name